# Differential equation for ethanol concentration in nth tank

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have the following problem to solve.

[image]

At first, I write the differential equation for the 0th tank as:

[image]

I go ahead and solve it and get:

[image]

Now, for the second tank, the differential equation becomes:

[image]

Solving it gives me that:
[image]

However, according to a later statement in the same excercise:

[image]

This means that I'm missing a factor of 1/2 for the equation of x1, which we can see if we substitute n = 1 in the given equation. Can anyone help me where it goes wrong in my differential equations?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found, $ \displaystyle x_0 = e^{-t/2}$

Now note that,

$ \displaystyle \frac{dx_1}{dt} = \frac{x_0}{2} \cdot 1 - \frac{x_1}{2} \cdot 1$

$ \implies  \displaystyle \frac{dx_1}{dt} = \frac{e^{-t/2}}{2} - \frac{x_1}{2}$

Solving we get, $ \displaystyle x_1 = c_1 \ e^{-t/2} + \frac{t e^{-t/2}}{2}$

At $t = 0, x_1 = 0 \implies c_1 = 0$

So, $ \displaystyle x_1 = \frac{t e^{-t/2}}{2}$

Similarly,

$ \displaystyle \frac{dx_2}{dt} = \frac{x_1}{2} - \frac{x_2}{2}$

Solving we get, $\displaystyle x_2 = \frac{t^2 e^{-t/2}}{8}$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes I can. Thank you alot!